# Using SQL to duplicate output lines across all periods

Tags: sql, join, google-bigquery, duplicates

I have an issue where I am joining a list of "User IDs" to a list of activity units for a given quarterly period. With that being said, the User's often fall in and out of quarters but I want the output to still show every quarter for every User, even when it is zero.

Table A:

| USER_ID | USER_NAME |
| --- | --- |
| 000123 | Gary R. |
| 000124 | Jane S. |
| 000125 | Mary K. |
| 000126 | John P. |
| 000127 | Hank B. |

Table B.

| USER_ID | QUARTER | UNITS |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 000123 | 2020-Q1 | 6 |
| 000123 | 2020-Q2 | 819 |
| 000123 | 2020-Q4 | 21 |
| 000123 | 2021-Q2 | 39 |
| 000123 | 2021-Q3 | 394 |

As we can see, User 000123 did not have any units in quarter 2020-Q3 and 2021-Q1 and I want the output to show those quarters with 0 in the units.

Example Output I want to see is:

| USER_NAME | QUARTER | UNITS |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Gary R. | 2020-Q1 | 6 |
| Gary R. | 2020-Q2 | 819 |
| Gary R. | 2020-Q3 | 0 |
| Gary R. | 2020-Q4 | 21 |
| Gary R. | 2021-Q1 | 0 |
| Gary R. | 2021-Q2 | 39 |
| Gary R. | 2021-Q3 | 394 |

The only thing I could think to do was to create a table with all quarters to join into the query but would like to know if it's possible to get the same output without creating an additional join.

Comment: Why are you hesitant about an additional join?  It is trivial and would solve your problem.

Answer (score 1):

Consider below approach

```
select user_name, format_date('%Y-Q%Q', q) quarter, ifnull(units, 0) units
from TableA a,
unnest(generate_date_array('2020-01-01', '2021-09-01', interval 1 quarter)) q
left join TableB b
on format_date('%Y-Q%Q', q) = quarter 
and a.user_id = b.user_id
```

if applied to sample data in your question - output is

[image]

Comment: @Matthew - have you tried?